# Why the implicit CASTing is happening during SQL Join?

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have two tables T1 and T2.

T1 has 3 columns t1c1, t1c2, t1c3 - all are of **String** types.
T2 has 4 columns t2c1, t2c2, t2c3, t2c4 - all are of **String** types.

I'm trying to perform a join as:

```
SELECT T1.t1c1, T1.t1c2, T1.t1c3, T2.t2c1, T2.t2c2, T2.t2c3, T2.t2c4
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.t1c1 = T2.t2c1 & T1.t1c2 = T2.t2c2;
```

But this is throwing me an error like this:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(CAST(T2.t2c1 AS DOUBLE) & CAST(T1.t1c2 AS DOUBLE))' due to data type mismatch: '(CAST(T2.t2c1 AS DOUBLE) & CAST(T1.t1c2 AS DOUBLE))' requires integral type, not double;
```

Then I tried this one:

```
SELECT T1.t1c1, T1.t1c2, T1.t1c3, T2.t2c1, T2.t2c2, T2.t2c3, T2.t2c4
FROM T1, T2
WHERE CAST(T1.t1c1 AS STRING) = CAST(T2.t2c1 AS STRING) & CAST(T1.t1c2 AS STRING) = CAST(T2.t2c2 AS STRING);
```

Then this error comes:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(CAST(CAST(T2.t2c1 AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) & CAST(CAST(T1.t1c2 AS STRING) AS DOUBLE))' due to data type mismatch: '(CAST(CAST(T2.t2c1 AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) & CAST(CAST(T1.t1c2 AS STRING) AS DOUBLE))' requires integral type, not double;
```

I want to work with StringType. How can I resolve this problem? And why this implicit casting is happening?

Comment: It would help to know what dialect of SQL you're trying to communicate with but I'm guessing that `&` isn't the same as the SQL standard `AND` operator normally used to join predicates.

Comment: Also, it would be good for you to adopt modern join syntax `T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON ...` rather than comma joins `T1, T2`. The modern join syntax was standardized in *1992*, you  should have had time to catch up by now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the solution. But can you please tell me why implicit casting is happening while I was using **&** instead of **AND** ?

Comment: `T1.t1c1 = T2.t2c1 & T1.t1c2 = T2.t2c2` apparently is parsed as `T1.t1c1 = (T2.t2c1 & T1.t1c2) = T2.t2c2`, with `&` a bitwise-and that requires a numeric type and thus the operands end up being implicitly converted. Add parentheses and/or use the correct logical operators (no pun intended).

Comment: Again, it would very much depend on *what the product you're talking to* defines the `&` operator as. It certainly seems to be treating one or more of its inputs as numeric but for more details, you should pay attention to what the [tag:sql] tag says and *tag your specific product*.

Comment: thanks, @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I'll keep it in mind. :)